# Change button background more times

Tags: android, button

I'm wrinting an application for andorid and I have difficulties with change buttons background. I have a simple button and when the users click on the button change the background. I'd like to make the button to turn back into the original form when the user click on it again. 
I have no idea how to do that, if anyone has one please response!

Answer (score 1):

use the android.R.drawable.btn_default  in order to change the button to default color

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't really understand. When I click the button first time something happens. But when I click on it second time another thing should happen. How can I do that in one onClick?

Comment: you can set a boolean variable and change it each time you click the button . inside the function check for the varible and change color accordingly.....if(myVar==true){mybutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);}else{mybutton.setBackgroundColor(getResources.getColor(android.R.drawable.btn_default);}

Comment: Yes! And could you tell me please how to change the boolean variable each time? Because when I create one I set it false. When I click the button I change it to true. When I click it again it will stay true. So how can I change it to false again?

Answer (score 1):

@Howlett Logan : You can try this way,

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="TextButton"
 />
```

Then

```
public boolean flag=true; // Global
Button buttonTest;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


 buttonTest=(Button)findViewById (R.id.button);
 buttonTest.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_drawble);
    buttonTest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            buttonTest.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image_1);        
        }else
        {
           buttonTest.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image_2);
        }
        flag=!flag;
    }
    });
}
```